# Solr request not fetching records from database

Tags: solr

I have made request to solr for fetching data from database. However, it doesn't fetch any record from the database. What could be the possible cause?
My data-import.xml and schema.xml looks good to me.

Comment: Start by looking at the logs, verifying that your connection details are correct, see what the status of the import job is, use the LogTransformer in your DIH configuration to get log entries with the data being imported, check the query log for your database to see if the queries are actually being executed..

Comment: @MatsLindh query is working fine in database

Comment: Could you share your schema and data-import? Hard to tell without details

Comment: @RohitRaghav Sorry, but that was not my suggestion - the suggestion is to look at the query log for the database to see if your query actually makes it way from Solr to your database.

Comment: Hi, I reloaded my solr_core and imported again. It seems working for me now. Thanks for all ur help.